# trying to create a list of dictionaries from text file

Tags: python, list, dictionary

So, i have this text file which contains this info:

```
rect 20 20 80 50 True
tri 80 50 20 35 False
```

What i want to do is write a function to read the type and coordinates of a shape from the text file and return the results in the form of a list:

```
readShapes('test.txt')
[{'kind': 'rect', 'bounds': [20, 20, 80, 50], 'fill': True}, {'kind': 'tri', 'bounds': [80, 50, 20, 35], 'fill': False}]
```

What i tried is this (granted it's inefficient but I'm just trying to be deliberate in my coding process for now):

```
# reads a file and returns a corresponding list of shapes
def readShapes(filename):
    my_file = open(filename, 'r')
    lines = my_file.readlines()
    fieldnames = ["kindVal", "x0", "y0", "x1", "y1", "fillVal"]
    results = []
    for line in my_file:
        dictionary = {}
        fields = line.split(" ")
        for i in range(6):
            kindVal = str(fieldnames[0])
            x0 = int(fieldnames[1])
            y0 = int(fieldnames[2])
            x1 = int(fieldnames[3])
            y1 = int(fieldnames[4])
            fillVal = str(fieldnames[5])
            shape = {'kind': kindVal, 'bounds': [x0, y0, x1, y1], 'fill': fillVal}
        results.append(dictionary)
    print(results)
    return results
```

Answer (score 9):

You could use [extended iterable unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/):

```
res = []
with open('data.txt') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        kind, *bounds, fill = line.split()
        res.append({'kind': kind, 'bounds': bounds, 'fill': fill})
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[{'kind': 'rect', 'bounds': ['20', '20', '80', '50'], 'fill': 'True'}, {'kind': 'tri', 'bounds': ['80', '50', '20', '35'], 'fill': 'False'}]
```

If the *fill* key needs to be a boolean, you could do instead:

```
res.append({'kind': kind, 'bounds': bounds, 'fill': bool(fill == 'True')})
```

Or perhaps, more secure:

```
# from ast import literal_eval
res.append({'kind': kind, 'bounds': bounds, 'fill': literal_eval(fill)})
```

Comment: Thank you so much! To clarify, the `*bounds` selects the values of everything *not* included in the other keys, like a 'first, rest' pair, yes?